# Alternative for Xuggle-Xuggler / FFmpeg in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, video, xamarin, ffmpeg, xamarin.android

For days I am trying to find a working library that can decode the video stream of the Parrot AR Drone 2.0. The problem is actually that FFmpeg isn't working in Xamarin Android and the Xuggle-Xuggler is only for Java which makes it really difficult.

Furthermore, I tried to use FFmpeg, but everytime I got errors like this: `DllImport error loading lbavcodec-55': 'dlopen failed: libavcodec-55" not found'.` I have seen a lot of possible solutions but nothing works. I also tried to compile some .dll files which contains the FFmpeg source code, but unfortunately the same errors as before.

I just want create a TCP video stream to "192.168.1.1:5555". After that I want to use a possible decode class/library which could decode the bytes to frames or something like that and put it on the view using a `VideoView`, so the frames will be shown on the smartphone.

Has anyone experience with this? Or does someone know a working library for decoding the TCP video stream of the drone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, because I just solved the problem.

There is a possiblity to use FFMpeg, but you need to compile this specially for your platform. Actually this is in Windows a little bit harder than in Ununtu/Linux. However, I tried to implement a pre-compiled library into Xamarin Android, but there were errors like `DllImport error loading lbavcodec-55': 'dlopen failed: libavcodec-55" not found'`, so that didn't work. Xuggle-Xuggler is a video decoder as well, but specially made for Java only and I am working in Xamarin Android, so I had to find something else.

After several weeks I saw a project which uses OpenCV. This could decode the video stream of the drone. However, there was this guy: https://github.com/AJRdev/ARDrone-Android-GEII who made the video stream in two different ways. Namely via OpenCV and a library called "Vitamio".

What I did was trying to use the Vitamio library which Xamarin Android supports. Because there is this Xamarin Android version known https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/vitamiobinding, but that's an old version, so I decided to use the Vitamio library which can be found here: https://github.com/shaxxx/Xamarin.Vitamio. I am using this library because it's using .AAR which contains the same files as the Vitamio library in the project I was talking about before and the most important, no errors appeared :)

Unfortuantely there is no information on the internet about the Parrot AR Drone 2.0 using Xamarin Android. So, if there is someone with this problem, then you could use the source-code of the official app called "Freeflight 2.4", because that one is specially made for Android. However, there is a lot of code in the Freeflight 2.4 app which takes a lot of time to get the video stream part, but I did not have the time, so I chose for an easier way as I explained before.

After the implementation you should be able to see the video on your smartphone!

Good luck!